# Some function to determine opening of virtual keyboard on Samsung Bada

Tags: javascript, screen, bada, samsung-mobile

I'm looking for some function to determine opening and closing virtual keyboard on samsung bada.
There is way to determine this?

I'm looking for it because when we focusing on text field - keyboard opening and "working" size of screen changes to: height of screen minus height of virtual keyboard.
Because we have a static height of the widget after the opening keyboard the height of our widget is still the previous size and there are the scroll bars. I'd like to find way determine real height of widget in case of open keyboard and in case of close keyboard.

Comment: well.. i solved problem with determining is keyboard open or not.. it's just analog of focusing at input field.  
  
but i still have problem with floating background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. i solved problem with determining is keyboard open or not.. it's just analog of focusing at input field.